# Cannot perform 'And' operation on System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlGuid and System.Boolean

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I have a `DataTable` with several columns in it. Some of those columns have data type `System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlGuid`.
When I run `DataTable.Select()` with following `sql`:

```
(GB_OH_OrgProxy = CONVERT(CONVERT('91ad5719-8d8c-4b32-93f1-ae338ad267c1', 'System.Guid'), 'System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlGuid')) and GB_IsActive = 1 and (GB_GC = CONVERT(CONVERT('03052ed3-2c64-49ac-97d8-c6079d5015b5', 'System.Guid'), 'System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlGuid'))
```

It throws `System.Data.EvaluateException` with message:

> Cannot perform 'And' operation on System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlGuid and System.Boolean.

It looks like `Ado.Net` data evaluator builds incorrect evaluation tree, even with added parentheses for around 'SqlGuid' fields comparison).

Do you have any suggestion how to solve this?

(I use `.NET Framework 4.6.2`)

Comment: Have you tried doing this with Linq instead?

Comment: Try to break it down to pieces - first only the first guid, than add the bit, and last add the second guid. You might find the problem this way.

Comment: After I run sql with first 2 parts, and then full sql - it works correctly and returns expected result. But if I just run full sql (even several times) - it throws exception.

Comment: I cannot use Linq - query is generated using other proprietary framework.

Comment: can you try this `
string query = string.Format("GB_OH_OrgProxy ='91ad5719-8d8c-4b32-93f1-ae338ad267c1' and GB_IsActive = 1 and GB_GC = '03052ed3-2c64-49ac-97d8-c6079d5015b5'");`

Comment: This fails with exception message "Cannot perform '=' operation on System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlGuid and System.String."